# How to hotplug pci/e devices in freeBSD? (Or How to remove and rescan/re-enumerate pci device?)

Tags: freebsd, bsd, pci, pci-e

I'm looking for a way to refresh/re-enumerate the pci device list.

In Linux, you can remove a particular pci device, and then after preforming a "rescan" the device will appear again. 
In Linux it is done by:

```
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/.../remove 
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

I'm looking for a similar functionality in freeBSD.

**What do I want to achieve?**

I'm using freeBSD and my pcie device can be reset from the host.  But when it boots again, it's uncommunicative, so I want to rescan the pci devices in order to initiate a new connection between the host and the device.

Any idea would be appreciated, even if it takes some coding effort.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PCI hot-plugging is being worked on, but I don't think it's supported yet in a released version. Ask on the `freebsd-current` mailing list.